# AngularJS ng-minlength not working when Value is auto populated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one input text box for Mobile Number that is given below

```
<input type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Example: (416) 111-2222" required
    ng-model="contact.phone" phone-input maxlength="14" ng-minlength="14" name="phone" digit-only>
<div class="error" ng-show="contactForm.$submitted || contactForm.phone.$touched">
    <span ng-show="contactForm.phone.$error.required">Required Field</span>
    <span ng-show="contactForm.phone.$error.minlength">Invalid input</span>
</div>
```

It is working fine when I manually input anything into that.

But when value comes from my Rest API and this time I have to populate this value into the same textbox. So when this value `1235455454` auto populated inside this text box and it is showing on a correct way `(123) 545-5454` but it gives an "Invalid input" validation error but the value is correct.

I am using AngularJS.

Comment: It isn't counting your spaces and () as characters as part of the min-length. So you either need to shorten your min length or change whats being counted to the min length.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ng-pattern by giving regular expression for it and use ng-messages than ng-show